# Sql select two digits values only

Tags: sql, select, sql-like

I'm trying to select values from my sql table (PHPMyAdmin) which contains only two digits.

So:

> IDNumber = '12'   //should be selected
>
> IDNumber = '34'   //should be selected
>
> IDNumber = '123'  //should NOT be selected
>
> IDNumber = '456'  //should NOT be selected

This is what I have so far, but this returns  nothing / zero

```
SELECT * FROM `TableName` WHERE IDNumber LIKE '[0-9][0-9]'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Sql-Server:

```
SELECT * FROM `TableName` WHERE LEN(IDNumber) = 2
```

Mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `TableName` WHERE LENGTH(IDNumber) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work in all database

```
SELECT * FROM `TableName` WHERE IDNumber>9 and IDNumber<100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE user_id REGEXP '[0-9]{2}' 
and length(user_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM `TableName` WHERE LEN(IDNumber) = 2
```